# maven multi module dependency version

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-3

I have a multi-module maven project: Module A depends on Module B. When Module B is built it is named ModuleB.jar and copied to target directory. Now in Module A's pom I have to put

```
<dependency>
  <groupid>com.mycompany.app</groupid>
  <artificatId>ModuleB</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have to put the version number, but then now I have two same Module B jars: `ModuleB.jar` (no version in name) and `ModuleB-1.0.jar` along with ModuleA.jar in the target directory.

I prefer to keep the version number out from the jar's final names since we have other legacy apps depending on these jars

Is there anyway to add Module B as a dependency in Module A's pom without the version number? Any clean solutions at all or am I just making life difficult for myself?

EDIT:
To clarify: These modules are built from a parent pom as jars and are copied, along with their dependencies, to a target directory outside of the project's parent directory. Hence the reason why there are two ModuleB jars: one when Module B is compiled and packaged with the finalname set as ModuleB.jar and one when Module A is compiled and packaged along with its dependencies, which includes Module B but with the name ModuleB-1.0.jar

Thanks!

The copy-dependency execution (I could strip out the version during the copy but then I would lose versions on 3rd party jars such as Spring jars =/ ):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${build.dir}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                <stripVersion>false</stripVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: As a start at least, if it's a multi-module project where all modules get built with the same version, then you should be able to specify ${project.version} instead of having to update that all the time. I don't think that will solve your actual issue though. Are the two moduleB jars identical (like same checksum and everything) just with different names?

Comment: @GerardRyan yes the ModuleB jars are exactly identical just different names. Take a look at the EDIT I made and it will explain whats happening

Comment: Can you include the parent pom xml that you are using to copy dependencies? I think the solution may be excluding Module B from the dependency copy.

Comment: @BobPaulin the copy-dependency goal is added

Comment: What about using excludeArtifactIds attribute?  You could exclude ModuleA.

Comment: @BobPaulin I used excludeGroupIds. I will provide my answer in a few minutes. Thank you for all the tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was that I was copying my internal modules twice: once when running maven-jar-plugin (with no version in finalname) and once when running maven-dependency-plugin, and both plugins are outputting to the same target directory giving me ModuleB.jar and ModuleB-1.0.jar.

So in the parent pom I configured the plugins:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${build.dir}/lib</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${build.dir}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                <stripVersion>false</stripVersion>
                <excludeGroupIds>com.mycompany.app</excludeGroupIds> 
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The first plugin is building all my child modules and jar'ing them to the output directory specified. the second plugin is copying all my module's dependencies to the same output directory in the first plugin sans the internal modules using `<excludeGroupIds>`

Thank you for helping me realize there was a simple solution!